# Redis pub/sub with lists

Tags: node.js, node-redis

I'm using Redis with Node.js.

```
client = redis.createClient();
client.subscribe("__keyspace@0__:url_set");
client.on("message",function(channel, message) {
    client.on('connect', function() {
        client.lrange('url_list',0,-1,function(err3, reply3) {
            console.log(reply3);
        });
        client.smembers('url_set',function(err4, reply4) {
            console.log(reply4);
        });
    });
});
```

Here `reply3` and `reply4` are `undefined`. Are `lrange()` and `smembers()` not allowed within a pub sub "on message" block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, regular commands are not allowed when a client is in subscriber mode. Create a another client for regular commands.

```
var client2 = redis.createClient();
```

use `client2` for `lrange()` and `smembers()`.

Refer node-redis [doc](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#publish--subscribe):

> When a client issues a SUBSCRIBE or PSUBSCRIBE, that connection is put into a "subscriber" mode. At that point, only commands that modify the subscription set are valid. When the subscription set is empty, the connection is put back into regular mode.
>
> If you need to send regular commands to Redis while in subscriber mode, just open another connection.

Comment: Will I receive the keyspace events if I use a different client?

Comment: yes, you will get the events to the client you subscribed from. Eg: ```client``` in you code will get the events because it is subscribed. And you can use ```client2``` for other commands like ```lrange()```